# Xamarin forms Activity Indicator Not Showing on Button click Even when Binding is true

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a **Activity Indicator** and have no issues with how it looks or anything like that, i just can't get it to to display on the button click.

There's a **Lengthy Process** that i need to go threw when Checking items out on the cart.

**The Method Structure**:

```
Button Clicked => Api Calls 
               => await IsinStock() 
               => Fetch Products 
               => await SingleCheck() || await VariableCheck() 
               => No Errors => AddOrder || Errors Display Error
```

My Indicators are being set to **Active before API calls** and **Ends after checks are complete** and it returns to add or show errors.

But it's just not displaying.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
              xmlns:o="clr-namespace:Octane.Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer;assembly=Octane.Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ecombeta"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             x:Class="Ecombeta.Views.Cart">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Grid
                RowSpacing="0"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--My Beautiful Ui Mark up here-->
            </Grid>

            <!--Loading Indicator-->
<AbsoluteLayout IsVisible="{Binding running}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <BoxView
                BackgroundColor="#80000000"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" />
            <StackLayout
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">
                <Frame Padding="20,15"
                    CornerRadius="7"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    BackgroundColor="Black"
                    HasShadow="false">
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <ActivityIndicator
                            IsRunning="{Binding running}"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            Color="White" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding LoadingIndicatorMessage}"
                            x:Name="lblLoadingText"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            TextColor="White" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>

            <StackLayout Padding="5"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="White">

                <ListView x:Name="cartView"
                          HasUnevenRows="True"
                          SeparatorColor="Black"
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"

                          ItemSelected="EvetClicked">
                    <ListView.Resources>
                        <ResourceDictionary>
                            <local:BgConverter x:Key="BgConverter" />
                        </ResourceDictionary>
                    </ListView.Resources>
                    <ListView.Header>

                        <Label Text="Shopping List" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,15" TextColor="Black"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Title" />

                    </ListView.Header>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Label TextColor="Black" x:Name="something" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                               Text="{Binding ProductName}" FontSize="Subtitle" />
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                                            HeightRequest="150"
                                            WidthRequest="150"
                                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                            Source="{Binding ImgSource}" />
                                        <Label IsVisible="{Binding _virtual}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           TextColor="Black">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="{Binding CartAtribKey }" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                                <Span Text="{Binding CartAtribValue , StringFormat=' {0}' }"
                                                      FontSize="Small" />
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label IsVisible="{Binding _virtual}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           TextColor="Black">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="{Binding CartAtribKey1 }" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                                <Span Text="{ Binding CartAtribValue1, StringFormat=' {0}'}"
                                                      FontSize="Small" />
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                        <!--<Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="{Binding PId, StringFormat='SKU {0:F0}'}" FontSize="Medium"></Label> -->
                                        <Label FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black"
                                               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                               Text="{Binding TotalDynamicPrice, StringFormat='Total R:{0,5:#,0.00}' }"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                        <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                                               Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference stepper}, Path=Value, StringFormat='Quantity {0:F0}'}"
                                               FontSize="Medium" />
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <ImageButton HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                         HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"
                                                         Source="https://mm-app.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/icons8-remove-64.png"
                                                         BindingContext="{Binding PId}" Clicked="Removevalue_Clicked" />
                                            <Stepper x:Name="stepper" Maximum="{Binding StockQuantity}"
                                                     Value="{Binding ProductQuantity}"
                                                     Minimum="{Binding MinQ}"
                                                     ClassId="{Binding PId}"

                                                      TabIndex="{Binding VariationId}"
                                                     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                     Increment="{Binding IncrementQ}"
                                                     ValueChanged="stepper_ValueChanged" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

                <StackLayout Padding="0" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <Button Margin="2" TextColor="white" BorderColor="#0088d3" BackgroundColor="#0088d3"
                            CornerRadius="10" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Buy Now!" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked" />


                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

```
private async void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    running = true;

    try
    {
        //You cant checkout if your not logged in There are no Guest Checkouts(I can But would rather not)
        if (Users.LoggedIn && _spamClick == false)
        {
            if (_orderlineitems == null)
                _orderlineitems = new List<OrderLineItem>();

            RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://xxxx/wp-json/wc/v2/","xxxxxxxxx","cs_xxxxxxxxxxx");

            var wc = new WCObject(rest);

            await IsInStock();
        }
        running = false;
    }
    (...)
}
```

```
public partial class Cart : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged 

private bool _running;

public bool running
{
    get => _running;
    set
    {
        if (_running == value)
            return;
        _running = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Note if `await IsInStock();` doesn't get hit, then the change will be to fast to see, also you need to make sure `running` is plumbed up correctly for Notification

Comment: Ooh yes ill update my qeustion with the running InStock always gets hit its a Failsafe to see if I checkout a item and buy it out but someone els has it in there cart that it notify's them

Comment: This should work, can you change it anyway?

Comment: I made an edit to your code, i noticed some brackets missing, do a double check and see if it's all ok

Comment: Try putting your loading indicator absolute layout at the end. Absolute Layout adds items to the screen in the order the XAML is, so I think what's happening is your indicator is getting hid under your listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I remember you posted a similar question a few days ago, but you deleted this question.

You said that you wanted to display ActivityIndicator when Button click, I test your code and find that there are two StackLayouts, one contains ActivityIndicator, another contains ListView, I suggest you can swap the positions of two stacklayouts, like this:

```
 <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout
            Padding="5"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="White">

            <ListView
                x:Name="cartView"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding products}"
                SeparatorColor="Black"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label
                                    x:Name="something"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    Text="{Binding ProductName}"
                                    TextColor="Black" />
                                <Image
                                    HeightRequest="150"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    Source="{Binding ImgSource}"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    WidthRequest="150" />
                            </StackLayout>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Button
                x:Name="getproduct"
                Clicked="Getproduct_Clicked"
                Text="load product" />

        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout
            x:Name="LoadingOverlay"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            IsVisible="{Binding loading}"
            Opacity="0.5"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ActivityIndicator
                x:Name="TaskLoader"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                IsRunning="{Binding running}"
                IsVisible="{Binding running}"
                Scale="4"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Color="Red" />
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>


  public partial class Page5 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<product> products { get; set; }

    private bool _loading;
    public bool loading
    {
        get { return _loading; }
        set
        {
            _loading = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("loading");
        }
    }

    private bool _running;
    public bool running
    {
        get { return _running; }
        set
        {
            _running = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("running");
        }
    }
    public Page5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        products = new ObservableCollection<product>();

        loading = false;
        running = false;

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void loaddata()
    {
        products.Add(new product() { ProductName = "product 1", ImgSource = "a5.jpg" });
        products.Add(new product() { ProductName = "product 2", ImgSource = "a6.jpg" });
        products.Add(new product() { ProductName = "product 3", ImgSource = "a7.jpg" });
        products.Add(new product() { ProductName = "product 4", ImgSource = "a8.jpg" });
        products.Add(new product() { ProductName = "product 1", ImgSource = "a5.jpg" });
        products.Add(new product() { ProductName = "product 2", ImgSource = "a6.jpg" });
        products.Add(new product() { ProductName = "product 3", ImgSource = "a7.jpg" });
        products.Add(new product() { ProductName = "product 4", ImgSource = "a8.jpg" });
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;   
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    private async void Getproduct_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loading = true;
        running = true;

       await Task.Delay(5000);
        loaddata();
        loading = false;
        running = false;

    }
}
public class product
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ImgSource { get; set; }
}
```

There is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yes Sorry i DId delete it as it got pushed to the void and honestly it was Phrased Terribly, I Gave it a try and Worked Wonderfully Thank you, I actually did end up using Popups instead just because I can Show alot more with them. But will keep this in the books